# Select statement between two table that don't have a similar attribute in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Say that I have an object named person which has (id, name, address, phone_number) as its attributions and an object named dog which has (ID, year_of_birth, breed). Then I have a relationship between the two objects named owner. Owner has the following attributions: (owner_id, dog_id).

On an E-R diagram owner would be a triangle connecting dog and person which are both rectangular. I'm giving this info just so you understand the relationship. my goal is to list the dogs ID's who's owners are NOT from Spain.

I've tried the following and dozens of different combinations like this:

```
 select id from owner where address <> '% Spain%';
```

Nothing seems to work. I've been stuck on this for a few good hours now.

Comment: Since `owner` allows for many-to-many relationships here between dogs and persons, how do you want to handle situations where one or more of the owners of a particular dog *are* in spain, and one or more of the owners of the same dog are *not* in spain? Also, does `person` not have some form of `ID`, the value of which is referred to by the `owner_id` in `owner`?

Comment: (One more follow up - it seems like a bad idea to have `is_only_owner` - can that not be inferred by there only being one row in `owner` with a particular `pet_id`? What does it mean if there are multiple rows for a particular `pet_id` and some or all of them have `is_only_owner` set?

Comment: My bad, I've added "id" to person. I only care about each person and if his location is in Spain.

Comment: Hey, forget about the "is_only_owner". I removed it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIKE` when using a wildcard comparison

```
select id
from owner
where address NOT LIKE '% Spain%'
```

For details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142

Comment: I've been using "no like" acually instead of "<>". I can figure out how to solve my problem though :(

Answer (score 0):

This will give the `dog_id`s for all dogs that have at least one owner who is not in spain:

```
select distinct o.dog_id
from owner o
   inner join
     person p
      on o.owner_id = p.id
where not p.address like '% Spain%';
```

Comment: It gives me the following error at "where no" (below the 'w'): "ERROR at line 1: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator. Any ideas how to fix this?